# Why is the output of this function 1?

Tags: java

I need an explanation of why this code prints "1", I'm taking my final exam tomorrow and this is a practice question that I cannot answer.... Any input is greatly appreciated!

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] values = {{3, 4, 5, 1}, {33, 6, 1, 2}};
    int v = values[0][0];
    for (int[] list : values)
      for (int element : list)
        if (v > element)
          v = element;

    System.out.print(v);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try "playing computer" with pencil and paper to understand precisely what the code does? Or if you have no paper, consider stepping through it with a debugger. It's pretty straight-forward.

Comment: your logic chooses the lowest number in the array.

Comment: `v > element` is the same as `element < v` -- that might make the logic more clear.

Comment: @RAY: then admonish the original poster for not demonstrating at least some effort which is an appropriate thing to do. Posting questions on this or any forum is a learned skill, one that we should help guide them towards mastering.

Answer (score 6):

Because the code below will give you the smallest value in your nested array `values`, which is indeed 1 in your code.

```
if (v > element)
  v = element;
```

*If `v` is larger than current `element` (ie. `element` is smaller than `v`), assign `element` to `v`.*

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through all the elements in the array and setting `v` to the element if it is greater than the element `if (v > element) v = element;`. Therefore, you will end up with the smallest value, which is 1.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think this code is supposed to do? Currently, it's printing the lowest number found. Why? Because for each element it performs the following check:

```
if (v > element)
    v = element;
```

...where

```
v = <the smallest number found so far>
```

- The first time through the loop the smallest number found so far is the first element -- `values[0][0]` -- because, well, it *is* the smallest number found at that point, since we haven't yet looked at any elements.
- Each time through the inner loop we compare the smallest number found so far to the current element. If the smallest number found so far is larger than the current element, then the current element must be the smallest number found so far.
- On each subsequent iteration, this invariant does not change. At the end of each iteration `v` contains the smallest number seen so far.

I strongly recommend stepping through the code in a debugger or (even better) writing down the steps on paper, testing the loop invariants at each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Well we need to check step by step

First

you got you main 2 dimensions array

```
int[][] values = {{3, 4, 5, 1}, {33, 6, 1, 2}};
```

Then you assign to a var V int. With the data of [0][0].

```
Note that values[0] = 3,4,5,1
values[0][0] = 3
int v = values[0][0];
```

Then the 2 for cheek each value in the array. First in
    values[0-1] and then values[][0-3]

```
for (int[] list : values)
      for (int element : list)
```

Finally you check if the V is greater than the new values you get. IF it is it substitute

```
if (v > element)
          v = element;
```

this code get's you the smallest number in the array. The first number. If you have two 1 it will take the first one.

I hope it help